How can we hear meteors? How can a material vibrate and produce sound in response to radio waves?
I first heard about this phenomenon in the April 14, 2017
Science.org news item New theory may explain the ‘music of the meteors' Electric fields could launch radio waves that generate sound. Basically it says that meteors produce very low frequency radio waves that some materials can resonate with, producing vibration and consequentially sound waves.
Well, how does that work? How can some material resonate with radio waves and vibrate?

Consider how an antenna works, particularly an antenna with real losses from, e.g., resistance to the induced currents.

@ScienceSnake lots of things "vibrate" but don't make sounds we can hear. I don't see how your comment is actually helpful to the post. Instead, I think a good answer might start with a review of On the electrophonic generation of audio frequency sound by meteors and Photoacoustic Sounds from Meteors (which offer two different explanations of "How can we hear meteors?" The a citation search to look for any additional work in the subsequent seven years following.
